# Is there any relationship between function composition and "decomposition" (Matrices, Manifolds, etc)?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

The linguistic similarities between "decomposition" and "composition" of a function never really dawned on me until today, largely because I have never seen "decomposition" used to explicitly related to function composition, despite decomposition operations being widely used in mathematics, from decomposition of a matrix, manifold, etc.

Further I am curious how or whether matrix/manifold decomposition theory can be explicitly related to function composition as matrix multiplication. It seems there is some link there but I am unable to find any resources explicitly stating it.

Comment: One assembles a unit from pieces (composition), the other take an entity and "de-assembles" it (decomposition).  There is no deep mathematical connection.

Comment: @Randall I'm aware of the linguistic connection as I mentioned - my question was asking more about how to explicitly relate the 2 in terms of common mathematical concepts; for example, what are some ways Matrix/Manifold decomposition could be redefined in terms of a reverse functional composition (in generalized terms). Such a definition is implicit in all of those notion, but is never explicitly stated as a generic way of defining them.